# How to delete on swipe an item from Filtered list? [RecyclerView]

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue while trying to delete an item from a RecyclerView after i've searched for it by using SearchView, while if i don't use the SearchView and delete the item normally it's works fine.

Here is an example where i'm deleting the item and where i'm searching for 2 deleting it and it still remain in the list.

[image]

While here is the method where i'm deleting the item on swipe in my Activity

```
  new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                itemAdapter.removeItem( viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                itemAdapter.removeItem( viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}
```

While here is code from my Adapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>  implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<ItemModel> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> mFilteredList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

    ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemModel> exampleList){
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        ItemModel item = variantiConstructors.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getCodiceArticolo());
        holder.qta.setText(item.getQta());

        holder.qta.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                variantiConstructors.get(position).setQta(holder.qta.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });


        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5C5C5C"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<ItemModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final ItemModel cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getCodiceArticolo().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variantiConstructors.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public EditText qta;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemModel> getList(){
        return variantiConstructors;
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        variantiConstructors.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes because you are not deleting the value from variantiConstructors list and mFilteredlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this i have made some change in your code

> MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ItemModel itemModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.btnShow).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showCustomDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        final ArrayList<ItemModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        RecyclerView myRecyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

        ImageView ivDelete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        ImageView ivClose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivClose);

        final EditText edtSearch = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("Nilesh", String.valueOf(1)));
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("NEEL", String.valueOf(1)));
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("Prem", String.valueOf(1)));
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("Rathod", String.valueOf(1)));
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("Android", String.valueOf(1)));
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel("Kanudo", String.valueOf(1)));


        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ivClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT || direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    itemModel = itemAdapter.getModel();
                    itemAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());


                }

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerView);

        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (edtSearch.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    if (itemModel != null)
                        arrayList.remove(itemModel);
                }
                itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase());



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

}
```

> ItemAdapter code

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<ItemModel> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> mFilteredList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    ItemModel itemModel;

    ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemModel> exampleList) {
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_layout, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        ItemModel item = variantiConstructors.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getItemName());
        holder.qta.setText(item.getQty());

        itemModel = item;

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5C5C5C"));

        } else if (position % 2 == 1) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<ItemModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final ItemModel cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getItemName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variantiConstructors.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public ItemModel getModel() {
        return itemModel;

    }

    public ArrayList<ItemModel> getList() {
        return variantiConstructors;
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        variantiConstructors.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T80bk0756xk

Comment: Now it's working more better but still if i search for an item delete it then i clear the edittext and delete an item without using the edittext when i close and reopen the dialog the item deleted normally appear again. but if i delete it again and close the dialog and reopen it it's going to be deleted

Comment: @JohnKarry *`when i close and reopen the dialog the item deleted normally appear again.`* than you need to delete item from your source also like `db`

Comment: the point is that i doesn't have any db... i Just have two EditText where i put in one BarCode and in another the Quantity then when i press "DONE" button they are going to be added to the arrayList

Comment: @JohnKarry share that code with question let have look in your code so i can help to solve that

Comment: btnConferma method and qtaControll are two methods where i'm adding items to the arrayList

Comment: While alertDeleteSingleItem, alertDeleteFinal and alertDelete are unused for now

Comment: You know i don't know where was the problem but seems it's solved. But in the adapter you deleted the TextWatched from which i was able to change values from recyclerView editText item can i put it back or that wasn't correct? anyway accepting your answer

Comment: Testing again i'm having the same problem :l

Comment: @JohnKarry sorry for late reply which problem you are facing right now and yes you can put that `TextWatched` in adapter class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180798/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code in the `getFilter()` method. You can clearly see that the filter keeps the list of item inside a temp list because during filtering the main list is switched out. So when you delete/remove an item from the filtered list you delete from the temp list, not from the main list.

Though there could be a workaround using `getFilter()` and `SearchView` I would recommend using a custom searchview which makes your task far more simple.

Comment: Which custom searchView could you suggest me to use?

Comment: You can customize an edit text...... I have made an investory app of the same type using this approach......

Answer (score 0):

Because You are removing the data from the list which you had populated with recylerView and you'r not removing the data from filtered list that why it showing..

```html
public void removeItem(int position) {
        variantiConstructors.remove(position);
        mFilteredList .remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue long ago. But finally I've found the work around.
Here is the adapter class:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder> implements Filterable {

private List<DataModel> dataList;
private List<DataModel> dataListUnFilter;

private RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener;
private SearchFilter mSearchFilter;

private String mSearchTerm;

DataAdapter(List<DataModel> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.dataListUnFilter = new ArrayList<>();
}

void setRecyclerListener(@NonNull RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener) {
    this.mRecyclerListener = mRecyclerListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.data_model, viewGroup, false);
    return new DataHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHolder dataHolder, int i) {
    DataModel data = dataList.get(i);

    dataHolder.tvSubtitle.setText(data.getSubtitle());

    String title = data.getTitle();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)) {
        dataHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
    } else {
        int startPos = title.toLowerCase().indexOf(mSearchTerm.toLowerCase());
        int endPos = startPos + mSearchTerm.length();

        if (startPos != -1) {
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(title);
            ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{Color.BLUE});
            TextAppearanceSpan highlightText = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.NORMAL, -1, blueColor, null);
            spannable.setSpan(highlightText, startPos, endPos, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            dataHolder.tvTitle.setText(spannable);
        } else {
            dataHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

// Filterable method
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (mSearchFilter == null) {
        dataListUnFilter.clear();
        dataListUnFilter.addAll(this.dataList);
        mSearchFilter = new SearchFilter(dataListUnFilter);
    }
    return mSearchFilter;
}


/**
 * Custom Filter class to overtake List Items issue
 * Delete Items while searching that are revised on refresh search
 */
class SearchFilter extends Filter {

    private List<DataModel> listToFilter;

    SearchFilter(List<DataModel> listToFilter) {
        this.listToFilter = listToFilter;
    }

    // Update Base Search List on Item Removed while searching
    void updateList(DataModel dataModel) {
        listToFilter.remove(dataModel);
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        String searchString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        mSearchTerm = searchString;

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(searchString)) {
            results.values = listToFilter;
        } else {
            List<DataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataModel dm : listToFilter) {
                if (dm.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                    filteredList.add(dm);
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        dataList = (List<DataModel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

/**
 * ViewHolder class of DataModel
 */
class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tvTitle, tvSubtitle;
    private ImageButton btnDelete;

    DataHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSubtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
        btnDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        DataModel dataModel = dataList.get(pos);

        mRecyclerListener.onItemClick(v, pos, dataModel);

        // Remove item from Adapter List and notify
        dataList.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);

        // Remove Object from Original Data from SearchFilter Class
        if (mSearchFilter != null) {
            mSearchFilter.updateList(dataModel);
        }
    }
}


public interface RecyclerListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position, DataModel dataModel);
}
```

}

Full Source: https://github.com/DekDhamecha/DynamicListSearch

When the item is being removed while searching, both ArrayLists i.e. ArrayList of Filter and ArrayList of Adapter have to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete item from the original list

```
for (int i=0;i<AppConstants.linkModelList.size();i++){
                        if (model.getID() == AppConstants.linkModelList.get(i).getID()){
                            AppConstants.linkModelList.remove(i);
                            filterLinkList = AppConstants.linkModelList;
                            holder.binding.expandable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
```